# How can I secure these two scripts used in SSH authorized_keys further?

Tags: shell-script, ssh, security

`itunes.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

set -f
set -- $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND

case "$1" in
  /home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/*)
    ;;
  *)
    exit 1
esac

command="${1#/home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/}"
shift
case "$command" in
  */*)
    # Simplest is to reject anything with a slash...
    ;;
  .*)
    # ...and anything starting with dot.
    # If you need to whitelist subdirectories of /home/dimm0k/progs/scripts
    # then you need much more sophisticated pathname parsing and care.
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac

exec "/home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/$command" "$@"
```

`rsync.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
case "$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND" in
  *\&*)
    echo "Rejected 1"
    ;;
  *\;*)
    echo "Rejected 2"
    ;;
    rsync*)
    $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
    ;;
  *true*)
    echo $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
    ;;
  *)
    echo "Rejected 3"
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: `authorized_keys` does not usually contain scripts...

Comment: @AlexP: the OP is referring to the little-known, but occasionally useful, `command=""` option, which vaguely speaking forces the command that is executed to something else (and not a general-purpose shell). Most common usage would probably be for version control servers, where you want to make sure the users really can only use version control checkin/out and nothing else with their ssh credentials.

Comment: @Ulrich Schwarz: You are of course right, and the fog has been cleared.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not really meaningful since you haven't defined any security objectives. “This is secure” is meaningless: secure against what? A security objective would be something like “an adversary who doesn't know the private key can't access any files on the system” (which your scheme obviously fulfills) or “an adversary who has no access on the system other than that key can only access files under `/home/dimm0k` and not run arbitrary commands” (which your scheme does not fulfill).

That being said, here are a few things you don't appear to have thought of.

- In the `itunes.sh` script, you have comments that claim that something is rejected, but none of your `case` statements contain any code, so the whole `case` is a no-op and the only filtering on the command is that it must start with `/home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/`.
- In the `rsync.sh` script, you allow any command that starts with `rsync`, not just `rsync` itself.
- In the `rsync.sh` script, rejecting `&` and `;` is bizarre. The string is not evaluated by a shell, so if you were thinking of the meaning of `&` and `;` in shell syntax, they're irrelevant. And if the string was executed by a shell then many other characters would be relevant, in particular `` `$|<> ``.
- In either script, you allow the caller to pass arbitrary options to the command that gets executed in the end. With `itunes.sh`, what this allows depends on what you have in `/home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/`, but it's probably not good. With `rsync.sh`, this allows arbitrary command execution, for example by passing the `-e` option.
- You do nothing to restrict what files the user can access. In particular, if `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` any of the files in`/home/dimm0k/progs/scripts/` is writable by the user then they can leverage a command to overwrite it and then log in a second time to execute what they've uploaded.

All in all, those scripts don't really enforce any security measure that I can see. For security purposes, treat them as allowing the user to run arbitrary commands. Functionally, the command mangling is bizarre and is likely to cause further escaping bugs when your scripts are used by a cooperative user.

If you meant to impose some restrictions on the user, you're very far from doing anything useful. Forget about doing it yourself and use a robust tool such as [rssh](http://www.pizzashack.org/rssh/) or [scponly](https://github.com/scponly/scponly). Investigate chrooting as well. Use a dedicated account with minimal permissions if possible. For better isolation, allow the user to log in only inside a container or a virtual machine.